# How can I compress a series of integers?

Tags: compression

BARF2 (Better Archiver with Recursive Functionality)  generates a huge barf2.count file, which is a number-only file. What's the best way to compress that?

Comment: What for? What's the purpose? Are you looking for an algorithm or a piece of software? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If running an external tool works for you, [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) is the best I've found.

It's open source, has a command line utility so it can be called from your app and has awesome compression ratios.

The link above is for Windows only, but there's a cross-platform option called [p7zip](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/)